# MFC MDI No Open Document = File New Disabled

Tags: visual-c++, mfc

For an MFC MDI application, if the user closes the last open document, the menus and toolbars are disabled, except for the File > Open command (menu and button). I'd like if the File > New menu and button item were not disabled. I've tried to find it by debugging through MFC but it's somewhere deep in the MFC framework. Anyone know please?

Comment: I think you may have a bug in your code.  I built a small sample MDI and the menu and toolbar remained enabled after the last open document was closed.  I'm using VS 2013.

Comment: I should have done that myself @rrirower - thanks! I suppose it could be a bug, but I don't know what calls inside MFC to look at.

Comment: MFC mostly uses the [Command UI Framework](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s7y0c550.aspx) to enable/disable UI elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the message map of your CWinApp derived application class, add the following line:

```
ON_COMAND(ID_FILE_NEW, OnFileNew)
```

Comment: You nailed it! For some reason i had that line commented out. Thanks!